# where is database file in the device

Tags: database, android, sqlite

iam trying to locate the database files on my nexus device.. 
is there anyway of doing it without rooting the device?

thanks

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that is only possible with root. you can use the emulator to get there... the emulator has root

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this is the path for the Nexus device, but on the Android phones that I have developed with, the path to the database file is `data/data/your_package_name/databases`.

When in doubt you can use the `adb shell` to `cd` to that directory and see if the database is there.

Comment: Yes i was looking for that. but i caouldnt see it, do you think the only possible way is by root it also?

Comment: Have you created a database to look for?